# Problems with memory allocation while drawing on canvas

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I'm writing my implementation of game of life. I'm using AvaloniaUI to make my program. I have Canvas as game field. I implemented the appearance of a live cell by mouse click (a rectangle of a new color), but the Dynamic Program Analysis outputs a bunch of issues about memory allocation.
My program works correct, but I want to deal with this issues. [image]

I have array to store states of all cells on my game field.

Here is some code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool[,] array;
    private int resolution = 10;
    private int _rows;
    private int _cols;
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
        _rows = (int)GameFieldCanvas.Height / resolution;
        _cols = (int)GameFieldCanvas.Width / resolution;
        array = new bool[_cols, _rows];
    }


    private void GameFieldCanvas_OnPointerPressed(object? sender, PointerPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(GameFieldCanvas);
        var x = (long)point.Position.X/resolution;
        var y = (long)point.Position.Y/resolution;

        if (point.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            var rect = new Rectangle
            {
                Height = resolution - 1,
                Width = resolution - 1,
                Fill = Brushes.Cyan,
                Margin = new Thickness(x * resolution, y * resolution)
            };
            
            GameFieldCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
            array[x, y] = true;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is some xaml:

```
<SplitView IsPaneOpen="True"
               DisplayMode="Inline"
               OpenPaneLength="296">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid RowDefinitions="30,Auto,30">
            
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="Start" Content="  Start " Click="StartButton_click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,38,0,0"  Width="80" Height="40" Background="DarkRed"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="Stop" Content="  Stop " Click="StopButton_click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="200,38,0,0"  Width="80" Height="40" Background="DarkRed"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="2" Name="Reset" Content="  Reset " Click="ResetButton_click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="130,38,0,0"  Width="80" Height="40" Background="DarkRed"/>
            
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewerGameField" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="1080" Width="1420" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Canvas  x:Name="GameFieldCanvas" Background="Coral" Height="1500" Width="1500"  PointerPressed="GameFieldCanvas_OnPointerPressed" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </SplitView>
```

I read that these issues can be caused by big number of drawing cycles. I think that I can create one `Rectangle` and draw it at any time, but how to place this rectangle with correct position on Canvas?